# Priority when applying nabla operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If we have a vector function A and a scalar function phi , if I want to calculate 
 $$A.\nabla\phi$$
Can I compute the divergence of A then multiply by phi ? as follows : 
 $$(A.\nabla)\phi$$
or we must compute the gradient of phi then dot product with A ? as follows
$$A.(\nabla\phi)$$
Are both solutions equivalent ?

(if you posted a link showing how to decide the priority of the operators I will be grateful )

Comment: Have you tried calculating each way to see what you get? This might answer your question.

Comment: yes , I did .. but I did not find them the same ! I felt not sure , maybe I used wrong calculation .. So I wanted to be sure whether they are same or not.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same. The easiest way to see this is to calculate for each ordering.

1)
\begin{equation}
(A\cdot \nabla) \phi = \left(\sum_i A_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \right) \phi = \sum_i A_i \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i} 
\end{equation}

2) 
\begin{equation}
A\cdot( \nabla \phi) =  A_i \left(\delta_{ij} \frac{\partial
\phi}{\partial x^j}\right) = \sum_i A_i \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i} 
\end{equation}

You can think of $\nabla$ as a vector of derivatives, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\nabla = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} , \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}, \cdots \right).
\end{equation}
You can then apply $\nabla$ first to get 
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^1} , \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^2}, \cdots \right),
\end{equation}
which you then dot with $A$, or first dot with $A$
\begin{equation}
A_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} + A_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2} + \cdots,
\end{equation}
and then apply to $\phi$.

The subtlety here is treating partial derivatives as elements of a vector and being careful with the ordering in the dot product: $A\cdot \nabla \neq \nabla \cdot A$.

Note that ambiguities in problems like this can be resolved by noting what the result must be (scalar or vector) and what the differential operator is acting on. In this case we must have a scalar since the vector $A$ is dotted with something, and the differential operator is acting on $\phi$ not $A$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This helped me a lot .. Does also (A x nabla ) not equal ( nabla x A) where x is the cross product. The same idea ?  (A x nabla ) phi : we apply cross product then multiply by phi , also the operator will differentiate phi not A ?

Comment: That is correct. ($\nabla \times A$) is the curl of A, whereas ($A \times \nabla$) is a differential operator that can act on $\phi$